# Business logic not on the presentation tier

Tags: silverlight, apache-flex, flash, architecture, ria

In a RIA application you are supposed to put as much business logic as possible outside of the RIA layers (flash/silverlight etc).  What is the reason behind this?  Any logic that goes into the presentation tier gets the benefit of executing faster...

Is this because the RIA technology will most likely need a face lift down the road and you will have to rewrite all the business logic?

Comment: Is a performance - security - maintainability game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with your premise, that you're "supposed" to put business logic outside the client.  You *are* supposed to move the business logic outside the UI layer, but there are typically still a couple client-side layers left before you hit the back-end web service.  A typical Silverlight application, for instance, is based on the MVVM model, which prescribes a View that has no business logic, a ViewModel which has a pretty good chunk of validation and business logic, and a model, which has the rest.  And all of that is on the client side.

On the other hand, you really need a business logic layer on the server as well.  You can't rely on a client-side application to filter out all the bad data: someone might be running an old version of the client, or a different client entirely, or might be trying to hack your system.

In other words, ideally, you should have your business logic and validations executing on both the client and on the server: on the client, because you need responsiveness, and on the server, because you need security.  The question is how to get this, and there aren't any perfect answers.

One approach commonly taken in Silverlight applications (I'm less familiar with Flash) is to use WCF RIA services, which allows you to create validations in one place that are executed on both the client and server.  Even if you're not using the WCF RIA Services framework, you can still get much of the same effect by linking to the source code of your validation/business logic classes on both the client and on the web service -- it's more work, but still probably less work than writing your validations twice and keeping them in sync manually.

Comment: premise not in putting something outside or inside or whatever, the busines layer was invented for simple and absolutely necessary reason - to share algorihtms between layers.

Answer (score 1):

Business Logic is a cross-cutting concern.

Will your users be entering dates?  If so, the interface needs to know they are dates to give them a picker, and to prevent invalid entries.  Maybe even restrict entries to a range.  That is business logic.  How can you keep it out and still have a meaningful interface?

Will users be entering at any time a US State or a Province?  If so, the drop-down list will have to be populated, and that means the UI "knows" about foreign keys.

Will there be fields the user can see but not change?  Why or why not?  That is business logic.  Will there be limits to what certain users can do based on certain conditions?  That is business logic.

This does not mean the UI knows about *all* business logic, of course, many data-moving operations have nothing to do with the UI.

But in the end the question is not how to keep BL out of the UI, you cannot do that, the question is which kinds of BL will be in the UI.  That tends to come down to types, ranges of values, allowed operations, and so forth.

So either the UI gets all of that information from a lower tier, or some of it is reproduced in the UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

So, one reason is maintainability.  If the client is already distributed everywhere, you don't need to require a re-install or re-download when a simple business rule changes.  Simply deploy the change to the back-end and you are all set.

It also lets you do things like hide your database behind your firewall.  If all of your business logic is in the front-end, it is likely that you need to expose the database publicly so that the business logic can be executed on the client.

But I fear that "business logic" is an overloaded term.  What is "business logic"?  The right architecture is the architecture that makes most sense for your application and needs.

As @Ken Smith said, you should certainly avoid business logic in your UI layer.  This is for testability, maintainability, designablity, etc.  But this does not mean that everything goes to the back end, especially in a RIA app with significant UI rules.  In an MVVM app (Silverlight) or Presentation Model app (Flex), you put UI BEHAVIOR in the ViewModel or PresentationModel layer.  Then, you put whatever level of business logic makes sense in your Model.  That business logic might just be some validation.  It might be more.  That is dependent upon your architecture.